# Cannot create offline bundle for react native (iOS)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Hi I was trying to create a offline bundle for react native iOS for testing using the following code

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

After doing this I tried to run the app using the command `react-native run-ios --configuration=release` once it is done the app opens and crashes instantly. So I used `react-native run-ios` this time the app opens with the local development server, if I terminate the development server then I will be getting **Unhandled JS Exception** error. For Android I tried the following steps to make it work.

1. `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
3. `react-native run-android`

Even if I terminate the local development server the app will work in Android. Any help for building offline bundle for iOS is appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

After bundling for iOS using the command

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

I'm able to generate **main.jsbundle** inside iOS directory and then followed the following steps.

1. Removed all the `App Transport Security Settings` and added `Allow Arbitrary Loads(true)` inside **Info.plist** file.
2. Edited the **Run Edit Scheme** to **Release**
3. Changed the **jsCodeLocation** from

   jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

to

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

4. **Product** -> **Build**

After following the above steps I'm getting the following error

```
File /Users/jeffreyrajan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app_prod-fnewtufemaynsoedmhggmfjynoti/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/app_prod.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with
+ echo 'React Native
```

Here is the screenshot of the whole error
[image]

Here is the project structure

[image]

**Current Version**:

- React : 16.0.0
- React Native : 0.51.0
- Xcode:9.2

Comment: You can see that the javascript build fails because `Cannot find module /users/jeffreyrajan/Projects/React-Native`. Given that your JS builds work in dev mode, this is likely to be an issue with Babel or the Metro bundler not resolving module paths correctly. Are you using any custom Babel plugins or Metro transformers?

Comment: No @jevakallio I'm not using any custom Babel plugins or Metro transformers, this is a sample project with just the default code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the build script that runs the bundler command does not handle whitespace characters in file paths correctly. I can see from the screenshot you posted that the path to your project contains a space character in the `React-Native Projects` directory.

If you rename the directory to e.g. `React-Native-Projects`, the Archive build will work correctly.

In general, it's a good developer practice to limit directory and file names to alphanumeric characters, because many Unix tools require escaping other character types.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jevakallio this helped me to fix the issue but I still wonder why it worked for Android.

Comment: The problem wasn't in the actual Metro bundling step, but in the shell script xcodebuild uses to invoke the bundler. On Android, the build is done as a Gradle task, so the shell script is not needed. I've submitted a PR in React Native to fix this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17628