# main.jsbundle does not exist. this must be a bug with + echo 'react native

Tags: xcode, react-native

I tried to archive my react native project using **Product** > **Archive** on XCode9.2. But Xcode produce this error:

```
File /Users/louis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scavenger-evyvzocndqoghkclcbwewolywniz/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Scavenger.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with


My Environment:
  OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
  Node: 9.3.0
  npm: 5.5.1
  Watchman: 4.7.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: ^16.0.0 => 16.2.0
  react-native: ^0.50.3 => 0.50.4
```

I also tried to run on terminal
`react-native bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/Scavenger/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'`but ended up with error Loading dependency graph...
    Unexpected end of JSON input

XCode error.

[image: Click here to see XCode error]

Comment: Might be better to post the relevant error message content in the question in addition to adding the screenshot

Comment: "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'" instead of this command I put node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' because of heap memory error But I am not able to find where is main.jsbundle. Any help on this?

Comment: check this video fixed the issue for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=180&v=eCs2GsWNkoo&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 158):

This issue take me some days to fix. I got this issue when running the build on travis-ci.
Here is my fix:

Add this line to `scripts` in your package.json file.

```
"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
```

Now you can run the command to generate `main.jsbundle`.
`yarn build:ios` or `npm run build:ios`

Open the Xcode > Select project target > add `main.jsbundle` to `Copy Bundle Resource` in Build Phases. (image below).

[image: Xcode fix]

Comment: I got this error: Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/(UserName)/(AppName)-IPA/trunk/node_modules (18ms) Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/(UserName)/(AppName)-IPA/trunk/node_modules (28ms) Loading dependency graph, done. warning: the transform cache was reset. invalid asset resolution

Comment: "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'" instead of this command I put node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' because of heap memory error But I am not able to find where is main.jsbundle. Any help on this?

Comment: the Copy Bundle Resources step was the key for me! thanks so much

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I got this problem after installing 'react-native-purchases' for some reason ( this library only work with rn version 0.64+ so maybe related with that..)

My question is.. should I run 'yarn build:ios' every time before I archive to deploy my app's new version?  

I'm so confused why It worked just well before I install 'react-native-purchases' and this problem happens after installiing it.. 
so adding this additional steps on my deployment process.. 
any information would be really appreciated!

Comment: This worked for me, i've create file main.jsbundle

Comment: It worked for me. -- adding main.jsbundle in xcode project > build phase.

Comment: I was able to archive successfully with this change, but the build no longer shows any assets.

Comment: any solution of assets missing with this steps ?

Comment: This worked for me flawlessly, thanks, Copy Resource step is really important

Comment: This worked me. Happened this archiving the IOS project. just run the yarn build:ios and copy that files to copy bundle resources. After archiving it worked well!

Comment: It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 32):

This happens when there is no offline bundle file in your project, I had the same problem and this worked for me.

I have added the below line to my package.json file, under `scripts` section, so I don't have to type it every time I want to generate an offline bundle.

```
"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/YourAppName/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'"
```

And then run this command in your application projects folder:

> npm run build:ios

After running the above command, new `main.jsbundle` will be generated in your `ios/YourAppName` directory.

Next, open your project using XCode, right click on your project name then click Add Files to "`YourProjectName`", choose the `main.jsbundle` file that was generated, and then build again.

Now it might be working well.

I am using:

```
 "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
 "react-native": "^0.48.3",
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Comment: For me, I needed to change `index.ios.js` to `index.js`

Comment: This should be marked as the answer!

Comment: It excludes all assets from the archived application ?
Any solution on missing assets ?

Comment: thanks this worked for me. I have added this line to my packages.json

`"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"`

and then run `yarn build:ios`, after that add the `main.jsbundle` to the project in XCode, it is directly added it to the `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phase`.

Answer (score 24):

Comment this line in AppDelegate.m

```
 jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

Use this line:-

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

After that run this to make jsbundle:-

```
 react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Run after this command in xcode .
Hope it will make bundle and there is no such error after that ...
Thanx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I did change the part of AppDelegate.m, and  gave me error **"Unexpected end of JSON input"** on terminal. Any idea why I get JSON error?

Comment: Please check ypur json data where you are calling your api and check also import ....sometimes it gives error of spelling too... so check any spelling in import and fetch properly ..

Comment: I got this error:
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/(UserName)/(AppName)-IPA/trunk/node_modules (18ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/(UserName)/(AppName)-IPA/trunk/node_modules (28ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.

invalid asset resolution

Comment: Ensure to delete the derived data  in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode before proceeding with the build after making this changes. It worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing this issue after I ejected from the expo to add in-app purchases.
I did the following to get it to work

```
cd <your repo>
npx react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --dev false --reset-cache --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios
```

**After the above commands are run you have to drag and drop the main.jsbundle and the assets into your Xcode and link it by reference and not group**

Answer (score 7):

**Recommend to use the latest Xcode and React Native versions.**
My React Native Version: 0.56 and Xcode 10

***Step 1:*** **Change AppDelegate.m** file

```
    //  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#ifdef DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

***Step 2:*** **Change Xcode Build Configuration to "Release"**

Goto Products> Scheme> Edit Scheme> change Debug to release

if you are using Xcode 10+ please change Build system to Legacy Build System under File> ProjectWorkSpace Settings> Build System

***Step 3:***  Upgrade your "babel-preset-react-native" to 5.0.1, if it does not exist in your package.json file please add it.

Remove NodeModules and package.lock file and add it (npm install or yarn install).

***Step 4:*** **Change ".babelrc.js" file**

Add " `presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]`

***Step 5:***  **Open Terminal**

Open the terminal and navigate to your project directory run this command

```
"react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets"
```

**this will generate a "main.jsbundle" file in iOS folder**

***Step 6:*** Add "main.jsbundle" file into Xcode.

Open Xcode and navigate to "Build Phase" under "Copy Bundle Resource" add "main.jsbundle" file.

Clean your project also clear your derived data in Xcode.
This will build your project in Release mode.

**For "Archive" error**

Add this dependency into your "*pod file"*

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'CxxBridge'
  ]
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

Remove pod and pod.lock and add again. (pod install)

***Happy Coding :)***

Comment: Vinod, this almost worked for me, then I got a syntax error for `react-native-input-scroll-view`

Comment: It's maybe because of your UI code. Please comment it and try.

Comment: Vinod, I removed the `react-native-input-scroll-view` and the `main.jsbundle` was successfully created, but how do you clear your derived data in Xcode because my app is still crashing silently even with `main.jsbundle`.

Comment: @Daniel Did you have any solution for this why it is crashing here

Comment: @sejn, sorry, I cannot recall how this was resolved.

Answer (score 6):

if you update the xcode and get this error then solution is

in terminal of your root project fire following commands

```
 1. sudo xcode-select --reset

 2. npx react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

during second command if you found any error relative to JS then fix it
After successfully running second command this error will be gone

Comment: that command is creating an assets folder that wasn't there before, many of the images of my app has disappeared too

Comment: Same thing happened with my Project also. It was working without all this stuff before, and now after running these commands local images are not showing in the app.

Comment: You should use GIT and GIT shows all newly generated unwanted images and raw files, delete that one, it will work

Answer (score 4):

You need to run the following command:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

After that, the app with the static bundle is installed on the real device. But because the nature of the static file, whenever I modify the source code, I need to run that command again to reflect the changes.
(You can see next error in command)

Answer (score 2):

This commnad works for me.

```
react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

Comment: again that's not a solution.

Comment: The issue was: the error in the js code when I tried to archive the app. But this command showed the line where the error was located in js and I could fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can just run:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Make sure you are using same node version in project and xcode

For me i had installed 2 different nodejs versions. when delete one nodejs it was working fine

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error at archive after updating from RN 0.53.3 to 0.55.4

```
/Users/<myuser>/Desktop/projects/<myProjectName>mobileapp/index.ios.js: Plugin 0 specified in "/Users/<myUserName>/Desktop/projects/<myProjectName>mobileapp/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js" provided an invalid property of "default" (While processing preset: "/Users/<myUserName>/Desktop/projects/<myProjectName>mobileapp/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js")

+ [[ false != true ]]
+ [[ ! -f /Users/<myUserName>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<myProjectName>Mobile-ghzbbftkebcwlvayfocqahvzifbe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<myProjectName>Mobile/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/<myProjectName>Mobile.app/main.jsbundle ]]
+ echo 'error: File /Users/<myUserName>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<myProjectName>Mobile-ghzbbftkebcwlvayfocqahvzifbe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<myProjectName>Mobile/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/<myProjectName>Mobile.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with'
error: File /Users/<myUserName>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<myProjectName>Mobile-ghzbbftkebcwlvayfocqahvzifbe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<myProjectName>Mobile/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/<myProjectName>Mobile.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with
+ echo 'React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues'
React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues
+ exit 2
```

A big importance to fix this had the line above the error related to **babel-preset-react-native**

After many hours of trying several workarounds I found a solution by downgrading `babel-preset-react-native` from `^5.0.2` to `^4.0.0` to make the archive process work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was caused by the javascript code. The error showed at the Metro Bundler(Command Line). Check the Metro Bundler, Does it have an Error or not.

Answer (score 1):

For some people like me this is simply an indication of an error in the JavaScript code. I discovered this to be the case after entering the following command: `npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --bundle-output "bundle.bundle"`. Android users would need to specify the platform like so: `npx react-native bundle --entry-file --platform "ios" index.js --bundle-output "bundle.bundle"`.

The bundle failed and the syntax error was shown. Any attempt to open the offending code in a simulator would show the error too.

Answer (score 1):

PFB the command I ran, which resolves the issue.

1. npm i
2. cd ios
3. pod install

Comment: In my case i ran the pod install without having run npm install

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after I rewrite shell script. **Project** > **Build Phases** > **Bundle React Native code and images**. There was blank space character in the script.

Comment: Can you please explain this, I don't understand. What did you do?

Comment: I do not see how this is relevant. Please elaborate.

Comment: I removed the blank character at the end of my script and it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by a space character in my project path: `/users/USER/Projects/Project HousePlants/`

That space in `Project Houseplants` the bundle can not handle and therefore can not find your `main.jsbundle`

Make sure that you have no whitespace characters in your path and try again.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280992/1116508)

Answer (score 0):

If properties of config file are changing at run time then make sure there is no error in that as well, if property is not set properly then main.bundlejs would not be generated.

For Example :

```
isSent:false, 
isShow:false
```

this two properties were setting at run time and found that for a particular record isSent and isShow were not set which made it

```
isSent:,
isShow:
```

at run time and caused error.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely stupid, but it happened to me, so I will mention it in case it happens to someone else:

This error occurred on **Product > Archive** because of a **missing dependency**.
Changes to `package.json` were not pushed with the code using the newly added dependency. x)

True story. (facepalm)

Another instance:
**import from a JavaScript file that wasn't pushed**.

Comment: Hey @Lazar!
Just wondering if you can help me out here. What do you mean by missing dependency. Also what do you mean by that Changes to package.json were not pushed with the code using newly added dependency?

Comment: My colleague added a new dependency, which was in their package.json, but they did not push package.json alongside files that use that new dependency, so my local project did not have the info on that new dependency. So the module was missing locally, but was being imported from in the app. x)

Basically, any import from files that do not exist shows up as this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have react-native 0.65.3, node v18.15.0 and xcode 14.3. Doing the below seems to solve it for me:

1. Adding `"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"` under "scripts" in package.json file
2. Run this `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` in terminal before building app

Hope this helps someone with similar env.

Answer (score 0):

I have react-native 0.69.6, node v14.21.3, xcode 14.3 and M1 Chip Mac.

First i created this clean.js script and added it to scripts folder to be able to clean the code.

```js
const exec = require('shell-utils').exec
const path = require('os').tmpdir()

run()

function run() {
  exec.killPort(8081)
  exec.execSync(`watchman watch-del-all || true`)
  exec.execSync(
    `rm -rf ios/build && (killall Xcode || true) && cd ios && xcrun -k && xcodebuild -alltargets clean && cd ..`
  )
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf node_modules`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ~/.rncache`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang.$(whoami)/ModuleCache"`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ios/DerivedData/*`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ios/Pods`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ios/build`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf android/build`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf lib/android/build`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf android/app/build`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf lib/android/app/build`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ${path}/react-native-packager-cache-*`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ${path}/metro-*`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ${path}/react-*`)
  exec.execSync(`rm -rf ${path}/haste-*`)
  exec.execSync(`npm i`)
}
```

I added this code to package.json into scripts

```
"clean": "node ./scripts/clean",
```

I run this script via `npm run clean`

then `cd ios/` and `pod install`

After this clean up I restarted my computer and resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In new version of React Native, maybe need to remove `react-native-cli` in global. So you should use this command:

```js
    npx react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an entry file called index.tsx. So in my case, I had to update the Bundle React Native code and images script by adding a line:

```
export ENTRY_FILE=index.tsx
```

This fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript then leave your project level `index.js` as it is without changing it to `index.ts`.

This solved the release build issues with me. Check this reference in here [react-native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#adding-typescript-to-an-existing-project)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who switched from a bare-workflow, to a managed workflow, ensure you register your appplication with registerComponent. [expo-register-component](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it started happening in an old app after I installed a new version of Node (18). Switching to Node 16 before creating a build solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

try this, go to Xcode and click on the expansion of the target like below image.

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyJtP.png)

Comment: Please provide a textual description you present in your picture.

Answer (score -4):

Simply cleaning the project in Xcode helped me

Comment: Didn't help at all.

Comment: in Xcode 10 clean build the Folder and Building,  solves the problem for me too