# Xcode archive error get error when i want to archive react native project?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, iphone-developer-program

I build a react native project and I want to export an IPA file from it but when I archive the project in Xcode It gives me this error

No member named '__rip'in'__darwin_arm_thread_satate'

how can I solve It?

[image]

Comment: Which version of React Native do you use?

Comment: my react-native version is 0.56.0

Comment: amir did you solve this? I now have the same issue.

Comment: this might solve your problem. Step 6 -> "Archive error"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645100/5662641