# building ios with eas build error: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory (in target 'Proj' from project 'Proj')

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

Does anyone has any idea regarding this error? this is when i  build react-native app using ***eas build -p ios***

```
>     ❌  fatal error: module 'yoga' in AST file '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/1LGSNG7MX55QB/yoga-KAR0AQ1TIRQP.pcm'
> (imported by AST file
> '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Proj-ehcxtkixfqmoxwfeifsbfvkxzqrg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Proj/PrecompiledHeaders/Proj-Bridging-Header-swift_2WZWZ3S1ZSPZV-clang_1LGSNG7MX55QB.pch')
> is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load
> '/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap'?
>     
>     
>     ⚠️  (ios/Origo_Keys_iOS_SDK/Debug/OrigoSDK.framework/Headers/OrigoSDK.h:45:1)
>     
>       43 | #import <OrigoSDK/OrigoKeysSymmetricKeyPair.h>
>       44 | */
>     > 45 | 
>          | ^ umbrella header for module 'OrigoSDK' does not include header 'OrigoDelegateProxy.h'
>     › Compiling Proj » main.m
>     › Compiling Proj » Proj_vers.c
>     › Compiling Proj » RCTOrigoSDKModule.m
>     › Compiling Proj » AppDelegate.m
>     › Linking   Proj » Proj
>     ⚠️  ld: method '+UIDatePickerMode:' in category from /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Proj-ehcxtkixfqmoxwfeifsbfvkxzqrg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Proj/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-Core/libReact-Core.a(RCTDatePickerManager.o)
> conflicts with same method from another category
>     › Copying   ./main.jsbundle ➜ ../../../Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/main.jsbundle
>     
>     ❌  error: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory (in target 'Proj' from project 'Proj')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [main.jsbundle does not exist. this must be a bug with + echo 'react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505446/main-jsbundle-does-not-exist-this-must-be-a-bug-with-echo-react-native)