# Xcode 14.2 Archive Error: Unexpected Failure during Archiving Process"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xcode, react-native

My debug app is work fine but when i try to archieve it gives error

Missing main.jsbundle during Xcode Archiving: A Possible React Native Bug"

The issue arises during the archiving process of the "Lehigh" project in Xcode, wherein the file path "/Users/saniyatariq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lehigh-ewjsysvwiumpbmflvexnlegluqrr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Lehigh/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Lehigh.app/main.jsbundle" is reported as missing. This error message suggests a potential bug with React Native, leading to the non-existence of the mentioned file. To address this matter effectively, it is recommended to report the issue to the React Native GitHub repository at **https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues** for further investigation and resolution.

When attempting to create archives of three projects in Xcode, it has been observed that only one of the projects successfully generates an archive, while the remaining two projects encounter an error during the archiving process.

i'm using

```
 "react": "18.1.0",
 "react-native": "0.70.6",
```

I m also using firebase

```
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^16.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^16.1.0",
```

The other which successfully create archive use

```
 "react": "17.2.0",
 "react-native": "0.68.2",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XatB.jpg)

Recently, while using Xcode version 14.2, the archiving process was functioning smoothly without any errors. However, within the past few days, attempts to create an archive have resulted in an unexpected error. The specific error message encountered is: "File /Users/saniyatariq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lehigh-ewjsysvwiumpbmflvexnlegluqrr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Lehigh/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Lehigh.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with React Native, please report it here: **https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues**."

Comment: Please help me resolve this error...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [main.jsbundle does not exist. this must be a bug with + echo 'react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505446/main-jsbundle-does-not-exist-this-must-be-a-bug-with-echo-react-native)

Comment: No this is not working in my case i add "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"in package.json add create main.js bundle add it in copy resources still getting same error on creating archieve